# How to change all icons in VB6 application?

Tags: vb6, icons

How can I make all the icons for the forms in a VB6 project the same as the main application icon?

Comment: I would prefer a tool that can be run over the `.frm/.frx` files.

Comment: It should not be too hard to write one, although it would be a lot easier to add "me.icon = form1.icon" to form_load() source, where form1 has the target icon. If the .frx files contain only the icon and NOTHING else, you can just replace it with the one you want.